# How to get the result of a node-sqlite3 query outside of db.get?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to check if the sha256 hash in my sqlite database matches the sha256 hash of the password the user sent to my NodeJS server. The Auth() function should return either true or false. How do I access the variable "refpw" in the if statement?

```js
function Auth(username, password){
  db.get("SELECT passwordsha256 FROM users WHERE username=?", username, (err, row) => {
    var refpw = row.passwordsha256
  })
  if(sha256(password) === refpw){return true}else{return false}
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that `refpw` is being defined in an anonymous function at some unknown future time, after the database select finishes. The Auth method will call the database, set the callback function, run the comparison of the yet undefined variable, and immediately return.

Comment: But if they don't match, shouldn't it return false? It returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is change an asynchronous method to a synchronous one.

I would recommend passing in a callback to your Auth method and then where ever you call the Auth method you pass in a callback function.

```
function Auth(username, password, callback){


  db.get("SELECT passwordsha256 FROM users WHERE username=?", username, (err, row) => {
    var refpw = row.passwordsha256;
    callback(sha256(password) === refpw);
  })

}
```

And then call Auth like this

```
Auth(username, password, (success) => {
  if (success) {
    //do something here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use async and promise..

```
async function Auth(username, password){
 const refpw = await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  db.get("SELECT passwordsha256 FROM users WHERE username=?", username, (err, row) => {
         resolve(row.passwordsha256);
        })
 })
 if(sha256(password) === refpw){return true}else{return false}
 }
```